# Unable to update the value of field inside class

Tags: c++, multithreading, message-queue

This function removes the expired messages from the messages container

```
void Broker::removeExpiredMessages(){
    while(true){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        messageMut.lock();
        std::cout<<Broker::getMessages().size()<<std::endl;
        for(auto& i : Broker::getMessages()){
            if(i.second.getHeader().expireAfter <= 0){
                std::cout<<"del"<<std::endl;
                Broker::getMessages().erase(i.first);
            }
           else
             i.second.getHeader().setExpireAfter(i.second.getHeader().getExpireAfter()-1);
        }
        messageMut.unlock();
    }
}
```

`Message.hpp`

```
class Message{
public:
    struct Header{
        std::string time;
        int expireAfter;
        std::string topicName;

        int getExpireAfter() const {
            return expireAfter;
        }

        void setExpireAfter(int expireAfter) {
            this->expireAfter = expireAfter;
        }

        const std::string& getTime() const {
            return time;
        }

        void setTime(const std::string &time) {
            this->time = time;
        }

        const std::string& getTopicName() const {
            return topicName;
        }

        void setTopicName(const std::string &topicName) {
            this->topicName = topicName;
        }
    };
    Message(){}
    void setPayload(std::string _payload){
        this->payload = _payload;
    }
    std::string getPayload()const{
        return this->payload;
    }

    void setHeader(const std::string& _time, const int _expireAfter, const std::string _topicName){
        this->header.setExpireAfter(_expireAfter);
        this->header.setTime(_time);
        this->header.setTopicName(_topicName);
    }

    Header getHeader()const{
        return this->header;
    }

private:
    Header header;
    std::string payload;
};
```

`Broker.hpp`

```
class Broker{
public:
    static bool isSubscriberLoopRunning;
    Broker(){std::cout<<"Broker()"<<std::endl;}
    static std::queue<const char*>& getMessageQueue() {
        return messageQueue;
    }

    static std::unordered_map<const char*, Message>& getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    static std::vector<Subscriber>& getSubscriberList() {
        return subscriberList;
    }

    static void pushNewSubscriber(Subscriber&);
    static void receiveMessageFromPublisher(const Message&);
    static void sendToSubscriber();
    static void removeSubscriber(const Subscriber&);
    static void removeExpiredMessages();
private:
    static std::unordered_map<const char*,Message> messages;
    static std::queue<const char*> messageQueue;
    static std::vector<Subscriber> subscriberList;
};
```

I m trying to make messaging system and I have a Broker as middleware for subscriber and publisher to share a messages, messages are stored in `unordered_set<const char*,Message> messages`.One feature of broker is that it automatically deletes the expired message, for this I have made a function running in a seperate thread detached from its parent thread.

My problem is it is not removing the messages whose expiration time has come, because the `expireAfter` variable is not decrementing even though I am doing it.I cannot understand why it not updating the value of the field `expireAfter`.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question. Pay attention that it's both complete and minimal, your's is neither minimal nor complete. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, once you have this running, consider filing it for review at codereview.stackexchange.com, I can already spot a few no-nos there.

Comment: What immediately jumps out at me is that you're erasing an element from a container while iterating over that container. That's usually a no-no, but according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map the `std::unordered_map::erase` operation only invalidates the iterator you just erased. So I guess it's fine. Just jarring.

Comment: `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000))` looks suspicious. Any time I see an explicit sleep (or similar) my first thought is "there's a bug here". What's the point of this?

Comment: Oh wait no you immediately access `i` after potentially erasing it. No bueno.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt okay I will keep this in mind

Comment: @JesperJuhl I have just used to get glimse of `std::cout<<Broker::getMessages().size()<<std::endl;` otherwise there will be much more output in console, only for debugging

Comment: @JohnFilleau yes sorry I have updated the code please have a look.

Comment: We really need a small test program that uses your classes and duplicates the error. You could be doing something crazy in your `main` and we'd never know unless you show us. [example]

Comment: @JohnFilleau will you be able to see the github for a example? as the it will be huge here.

Comment: @Abhinav. The point isn't to include the entire program that you currently have. The point is to write a small program that exercises enough of your code to duplicate the error. A main that could accomplish this shouldn't need to be more than a few lines to duplicate the error.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I got the answer thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this to return a reference

```
Header &getHeader() const{
    return this->header;
}
```

It is returning by value and not by reference right now. That is why the expire time is not decrementing!